# Astrophysical situation to test this theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, gravity, equivalence-principle

### Question

I believe the following uncertainty principle to be true in the regime $ v << c$ :

$$ \Delta g \Delta p \geq | \langle \dot U \rangle - \langle p \rangle \langle g \rangle|$$

Is there any astrophysical situation which can test this?

### Background

I recently had the following idea in the regime of quantum mechanics and gravity $ v << c$: we can the Heisenberg picture we define an acceleration operator and using Einstein's equivalence principle we state it must be equivalent to $g$ operator (quantum mechanical version of $g$ field) and thus we proceed to find an uncertainty principle.

### Mathematical Details

We use the heisenberg picture to define velocity $\hat v$:

$$ \hat v = \frac{dU^\dagger x U}{dt} = U^\dagger\frac{[H,x]}{- i \hbar}U$$

Now we can again differentiate to get acceleration $\hat a$:

$$ \hat a =  \hat U^\dagger\frac{[[\hat H, \hat x], \hat x]}{-i \hbar} \hat U =  \hat U^\dagger\frac{(\hat H^2 \hat x + \hat x \hat H^2 - 2\hat H \hat x \hat H)}{\hbar^2} \hat U $$

We can simplify the calculation by splitting the Hamiltonian into potential  $ \hat V $ and kinetic energy $ \hat T $: $\hat H = \hat T + \hat V$

By noticing (one can also calculate this) that the acceleration of an object in a constant potential is $0$:

$$ \hat 0 = \hat T^2 x + x  \hat T^2 - 2 \hat T  \hat x  \hat T $$

We also know $ [\hat V, \hat x] = 0 $ as potential is a function of position. Thus, we can simplify acceleration as:

$$ \hat a = \hat V \hat T \hat x + \hat x \hat T \hat V - \hat V \hat x \hat T - \hat T \hat x \hat V   $$

Now from the equivalence principle we know that the effect of acceleration is indistinguishable from gravity. Using this fact:

$$ \hat g = \hat a $$

However, $\hat g$ does not commute with $\hat p$ (it commutes with position). Using the anti-commutator (rather than the commutator) we should observe:

$$ \Delta g \Delta p \geq | \langle \dot U \rangle - \langle p \rangle \langle g \rangle|$$

By Schwatz inequality $ | \langle \dot U \rangle - \langle p \rangle \langle g \rangle| $ is $0$ only when $U$ is constant.

Comment: What, exactly, is the operator $\hat{g}$ supposed to be here?

Comment: So Im trying to unify QM and gravity (equivalence principle) rather than QFT and GR ... $\hat g$ is suppose to be a quantum mechanical version of the gravitational field ... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gravitational_field

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer, just a number of observations that are too long for comments:

1) You have some issues in your first 2 eq. lines, check the factor for the commutator in the time derivative and the double commutator in your definition of ${\hat a}$.

2) I think you have a nice catch with 
$$
\left[\;\frac{d^2{\hat x}}{dt^2}, \;{\hat x}\right] = 0
$$
and the idea of the uncertainty relation, even if you do not invoke the equivalence principle, which is kinda tricky. But,

3) I suppose you use $\langle \dot{U}\rangle$ in the uncertainty relation in anticipation of a more general form for ${\hat T}$, but when  ${\hat T} = {\hat p}^2/2m\;$ your ${\hat a}$ simplifies to
$$
{\hat a} = \frac{i}{m\hbar}\left[ {\hat V},\;{\hat p}\right]
$$
and
$$
\Big\{{\hat a}, \;{\hat p} \Big\} = \frac{i}{m\hbar} \Big\{\left[\; {\hat V},\;{\hat p}\;  \right], \; {\hat p} \Big\} = [{\hat H}, {\hat T}] = 2 \frac{d{\hat T}}{dt}
$$

4) On the other hand, if you rewrite the inequality using $2 d{\hat T}/dt$ instead of $\langle \dot{U}\rangle$, I think you'll find that it doesn't say much without the commutator term that you chose to discard. The reason is that it becomes
$$
\Delta \left(\frac{1}{m}\frac{d{\hat p}}{dt}\right) \;\Delta {\hat p} \ge \Big| \Big\langle \frac{d{\hat T}}{dt}\Big \rangle - \langle {\hat p}\rangle \Big\langle \frac{1}{m}\frac{d{\hat p}}{dt} \Big\rangle   \Big| =\\
= \frac{1}{2m}\Big| \Big\langle {\hat p} \frac{d{\hat p}}{dt} + \frac{d{\hat p}}{dt}{\hat p} \Big\rangle  - 2 \langle {\hat p}\rangle \Big\langle \frac{d{\hat p}}{dt} \Big\rangle   \Big| = \frac{1}{2m} \Big| \Big\langle\Big\{{\hat p} - \langle {\hat p} \rangle , \frac{d{\hat p}}{dt} - \langle \frac{d{\hat p}}{dt} \rangle  \Big\} \Big\rangle \Big|
$$
or 
$$
\frac{1}{2} \frac{\Big|\Big\langle\Big\{{\hat p} - \langle {\hat p} \rangle , d{\hat p}/dt - \langle d{\hat p}/dt \rangle  \Big\} \Big\rangle \Big|}{\Delta (d{\hat p}dt) \;\Delta {\hat p}} \le 1
$$
But now the left hand side is just a symmetrized [Pearson's correlation coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pearson_correlation_coefficient) (accounting for non-commuting observables), and this uncertainty relation is only telling us the trivial fact that the Pearson coefficient must be less than 1 (it always is).

That is, if you want a more meaningful uncertainty relation you have to keep the commutator alongside the correlation terms.

Comment: would it be fair to say that if my derivation holds then from only quantum mechanics and general relativity we can argue that the gravitational field must have momentum?

Comment: I wouldn't go that far, in this context. First, to have a "momentum" for the gravitational field, I think you must have the field as some kinda of "coordinate", which is not the case here. Second, you are trying to invoke the equivalence principle in a situation where (average) acceleration is clearly due to the presence of another interaction $V$. That is, no $V$ means no acceleration, you are working in flat space.

Comment: At best, you might consider a similar approach in the context of quantization in arbitrary curvilinear coordinates (without background flat space), in which case you might be able to link average acceleration to average space curvature, and then get your uncertainty relation from there. Not my turf really, but see https://lib-extopc.kek.jp/preprints/PDF/1994/9402/9402205.pdf, with the caveat that everything is a plain non-relativistic theory.

Comment: And yet, the interesting nugget I think you have is the focus on particle acceleration, because we usually default to the end result of $ force = -\nabla V$ and kinda forget that even in QM we can measure position and force (or acceleration) simultaneously, never mind any uncertainty relations that measuring force through acceleration, or conversely, might entail.